# Call to the function failing with : ORA-00904: "TEMP_DATA"."P_LNAME": invalid identifier

Tags: oracle, plsql

The following function compiles fine. But when a call is made to the function in an anonymous PL/SQL code, the call fails.
Can anyone please suggest why ? I am trying to insert the un-matched (new) data and update the matching (existing) data.

```
Function Fn_Insert_Data_Using_Merge (p_Id in Number,
                                     p_fname in varchar2,
                                     p_mname in varchar2,
                                     p_lname in varchar2,
                                     p_birth_date in date) Return Boolean
Is
Begin
  Dbms_Output.put_line ('Inside the function Fn_Insert_Data_Using_Merge ...');
  Merge Into test_employee te
    using (select distinct p_Id, p_fname, p_mname, p_lname, p_birth_date
             from test_employee) temp_data
    on (te.first_name = temp_data.p_fname and
        te.middle_name = temp_data.p_mname and
        te.last_name = temp_data.p_lname)
    when matched then 
      update
        set first_name = p_fname,
            middle_name = p_mname,
            last_name = p_lname,
            run_status = 'Updated'
    when not matched then
      insert (id, first_name, middle_name, last_name, birth_date, run_status)
        values
             (p_id, p_fname, p_mname, p_lname, p_birth_date, 'Inserted');

  Dbms_Output.put_line ('Returning successfully from the function Fn_Insert_Data_Using_Merge ...');
  Return True;
Exception
  When Dup_Val_On_Index Then
    Dbms_Output.put_line ('The name already exists...Cannot insert again ..');
    Return False;
  When Others Then
    Dbms_Output.put_line ('Facing some critical error : ' || SQLERRM);
    Return False;
End Fn_Insert_Data_Using_Merge;
```

Comment: What is the line number of the error?

Comment: (te.first_name = temp_data.p_fname and te.middle_name = temp_data.p_mname and te.last_name = temp_data.p_lname)

Comment: ORA-06512: at "FC113EXT.PKG_TEST", line 101
   ORA-00904: "TEMP_DATA"."P_LNAME": invalid identifier

line 101 is "Merge Into test_employee te" statement..

Comment: Are you trying to call this function through an SQL query?

Comment: No . it is being called from an anonymous PL/SQL block of code ..

declare 
l_first_name varchar2(25) := 'Anub';
l_middle_name varchar2(25) := 'D.';
l_last_name varchar2(25) := 'Mathew';
l_birth_date date := to_date ('15121992', 'dd-mm-yyyy');
begin                                                                              
    If Not pkg_test.Fn_Insert_Data_Using_Merge (l_first_name,                                                                          l_middle_name,
l_last_name,
l_birth_date) Then
.

Answer (score 0):

The error is trying to tell you that there is no column in your TEMP_DATA extract named P_LNAME.  There is a parameter to the function named 'p_lname' but in the extract you've assigned no column aliases so there are no named fields.  In addition (although not a cause of the error), doing a DISTINCT from a table with potentially many rows is a slow way to get the function parameters into the temp table in the USING clause; you'd be better off using a SELECT...FROM DUAL.  Try replacing your MERGE statement with the following and let us know how it goes:

```
Merge Into test_employee te
using (select p_Id as p_Id,
              p_fname as p_fname,
              p_mname as p_mname,
              p_lname as p_lname,
              p_birth_date as p_birth_date
         from dual) temp_data
on (te.first_name = temp_data.p_fname and
    te.middle_name = temp_data.p_mname and
    te.last_name = temp_data.p_lname)
when matched then 
  update
    set first_name = temp_data.p_fname,
        middle_name = temp_data.p_mname,
        last_name = temp_data.p_lname,
        run_status = 'Updated'
when not matched then
  insert (id,                first_name,             middle_name,
          last_name,         birth_date,             run_status)
    values
         (temp_data.p_id,    temp_data.p_fname,      temp_data.p_mname, 
          temp_data.p_lname, temp_data.p_birth_date, 'Inserted');
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks Bob. The code runs fine after making just one change. When i was using your updated code, i was getting the exception saying "The columns mentioned in ON CLAUSE cannot be updated." When i removed those columns, the code worked as per the expected functionality.